# Which Table Will Get Locked With This Query

Tags: mariadb, locking, tokudb

```
INSERT INTO stats.cps
(time_stamp,entries,cust_id)
select start_time, count(*) , c_id from gb.str
where start_time between '$DATE10' and '$DATE'

group by start_time, src_id
order by start_time ASC
```

I had this query on a machine remote to the DB server and `start_time` wasn't an index so it was taking a while. I noticed on performance graphs the times it was executing there were spikes of increased load as expected that stopped appearing when I stopped the script that was executing the query.

Another application was misbehaving at those exact times, but that application used the `gb.str` table and not `stats` db where the data was inserted. The developers of that application think that this query was the reason for the poor performance of their application but `gb.str` shouldn't have been locked is my assumption. I ran long SELECT queries on `gb.str` to see if that application is getting a performance hit but it doesn't..

Would the query also lock `gb.str` to some extent? All the tables are TokuDB that came in with the MariaDB (`10.0.22-MariaDB`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I interpret [Transactions and Concurrency](https://github.com/percona/tokudb-engine/wiki/Transactions-and-Concurrency) on the TokuDB wiki

> **Insert select**
>
> - Serializable
> - Grab read locks on all key ranges read by query
> - Grab write locks on all keys written
> - Repeatable read
> - Grab read locks on all key ranges read by query
> - Grab write locks on all keys written
> - Read committed
> - Grab write locks on all keys written
> - Read uncommitted
> - Grab write locks on all keys written

Inserts by the 3rd party application would need to update the keys and they may happen to be locked for certain rows that at the same time are selected-to-be-inserted by that query.

The way I solved it in my case which is make the query run for time slices slightly in the past so it cannot coincide with that application (which actually adds the data).